# How to upload a file to a web server

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I'm trying to send different types of files to myself over my local network using PowerShell. I think I'm onto something with the command;

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://192.168.0.164:8000/upload -Method Post -InFile "file.txt"`
```

But sadly, I get this response;

```
    Invoke-RestMethod :

        Error response

        Error response
        Error code: 400
        Message: Field "files" not found.
        Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.
```

The server I'm trying to upload to is just a python module called uploadserver;
https://pypi.org/project/uploadserver/

How can I use PowerShell to upload files?

Answer (score 1):

If the server is on your local network you could mount the server as a network drive and simply run

```
Copy-item ./file.txt ./destinationdrive
```

Or you can use remoting
So from your logged in session

```
$remote_session = New-PSsession
Copy-item ./file.txt -tosession $remote_session ./filepath/file.txt
```